# Angular 9 / Typescript merge multiple object arrays on multiple keys

Tags: c#, typescript

I've got two JSON objects (printed here using JSON.stringify(array of objects))
GPRows data is

```
[
   {
      "shopName":"Testing One",
      "state":"NSW",
      "yearMonth":"20203",
      "id":29,
      "shopId":1,
      "paintSale":80000,
      "panelSale":80000,
      "partsSale":80000,
      "otherSale":80000,
      "paintCost":80000,
      "panelCost":80000,
      "partsCost":80000,
      "otherCost":80000,
      "panelWages":80000,
      "paintWages":80000,
      "depreciation":80000,
      "forecastedSales":80000,
      "expenses":80001
   },
   {
      "shopName":"Not yours",
      "state":"SA",
      "yearMonth":"20204",
      "id":28,
      "shopId":2,
      "paintSale":85000,
      "panelSale":80000,
      "partsSale":80000,
      "otherSale":80000,
      "paintCost":80000,
      "panelCost":80000,
      "partsCost":80000,
      "otherCost":80000,
      "panelWages":80000,
      "paintWages":80000,
      "depreciation":80000,
      "forecastedSales":80000,
      "expenses":80000
   },
   {
      "shopName":"Testing One",
      "state":"NSW",
      "yearMonth":"20201",
      "id":31,
      "shopId":1,
      "paintSale":75000,
      "panelSale":75000,
      "partsSale":75000,
      "otherSale":75000,
      "paintCost":60000,
      "panelCost":42000,
      "partsCost":45000,
      "otherCost":20000,
      "panelWages":75000,
      "paintWages":75000,
      "depreciation":75000,
      "forecastedSales":75000,
      "expenses":75000
   }
]
```

and

BudgetTargets data is

```
[
   {
      "shopName":"Testing One",
      "state":"NSW",
      "yearMonth":"20202",
      "shopId":1,
      "sales":487500,
      "costs":80000,
      "expenses":90000,
      "netprofit":25000,
      "arc":2100,
      "numVehicles":232,
      "ppv":108,
      "wagesperc":10,
      "gPperc":40
   },
   {
      "shopName":"Not yours",
      "state":"SA",
      "yearMonth":"20204",
      "shopId":2,
      "sales":487500,
      "costs":80000,
      "expenses":90000,
      "netprofit":25000,
      "arc":2100,
      "numVehicles":232,
      "ppv":108,
      "wagesperc":10,
      "gPperc":40
   }
]
```

I either want to map them together on yearMonth and shopId? or since they have the same value names (which i don't want to overwrite) maybe a function so that I can query BudgetTargets value for this specific entry in my angular when I *ngFor loop the GPRows array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the **GPRows** list and check if there is an element conforming to the condition on the **BudgetTargets** list, then merging the two on a object ,else just returns the **GPRows item**

```js
const GPRows = [ { "shopName": "Testing One", "state": "NSW", "yearMonth": "20203", "id": 29, "shopId": 1, "paintSale": 80000, "panelSale": 80000, "partsSale": 80000, "otherSale": 80000, "paintCost": 80000, "panelCost": 80000, "partsCost": 80000, "otherCost": 80000, "panelWages": 80000, "paintWages": 80000, "depreciation": 80000, "forecastedSales": 80000, "expenses": 80001 }, { "shopName": "Not yours", "state": "SA", "yearMonth": "20204", "id": 28, "shopId": 2, "paintSale": 85000, "panelSale": 80000, "partsSale": 80000, "otherSale": 80000, "paintCost": 80000, "panelCost": 80000, "partsCost": 80000, "otherCost": 80000, "panelWages": 80000, "paintWages": 80000, "depreciation": 80000, "forecastedSales": 80000, "expenses": 80000 }, { "shopName": "Testing One", "state": "NSW", "yearMonth": "20201", "id": 31, "shopId": 1, "paintSale": 75000, "panelSale": 75000, "partsSale": 75000, "otherSale": 75000, "paintCost": 60000, "panelCost": 42000, "partsCost": 45000, "otherCost": 20000, "panelWages": 75000, "paintWages": 75000, "depreciation": 75000, "forecastedSales": 75000, "expenses": 75000 } ];

const BudgetTargets = [ { "shopName": "Testing One", "state": "NSW", "yearMonth": "20203", "shopId": 1, "sales": 487500, "costs": 80000, "expenses": 90000, "netprofit": 25000, "arc": 2100, "numVehicles": 232, "ppv": 108, "wagesperc": 10, "gPperc": 40 }, { "shopName": "Not yours", "state": "SA", "yearMonth": "20204", "shopId": 2, "sales": 487500, "costs": 80000, "expenses": 90000, "netprofit": 25000, "arc": 2100, "numVehicles": 232, "ppv": 108, "wagesperc": 10, "gPperc": 40 } ];

const dataMerged = GPRows.map(GPItem => {
    const budgetTargetItem = BudgetTargets.find(bTItem =>
        bTItem.yearMonth == GPItem.yearMonth && bTItem.shopId ==
        GPItem.shopId);
    return budgetTargetItem !== undefined ? {
        ...GPItem,
        ...budgetTargetItem
    } : GPItem
});

document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML =  "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(dataMerged,null, 2) +"</pre>";
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: this is my result. doesn't look right to what I wanted? https://pastebin.com/rgN6WN0y

Comment: I'm sur you forgot something , i juste edit the answer by add code snippet  for better understand , I hope it will help you